# How to make two records from one?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have records with the following:

```
Id    Date          MondayMorning  MondayEvening  TuesdayMorning, and so on
1   2012-01-01          2               3   
2   2012-01-01          2               2
```

I want split record 1 in two records because the states of mondaymorning and mondayevening are not the same. If the state is the same then do nothing.

The result that I expect:

```
Id    Date          MondayMorning  MondayEvening  TuesdayMorning
1   2012-01-01          2               NULL          2
1   2012-01-01          NULL            3             2
2   2012-01-01          2               2
```

Please remember that also the other days can vary.

How can I do this?

Comment: So what will be the desired output

Comment: do you mean to say you want as many records as there are `mondaymorning` and `mondayevening` differences?

Comment: could you please edit your post to write the required output with few more input possibilities..

Answer (score 4):

I do not completely understand the output you require but the following script will give you all the records in the table and then all the records with the MondayMorning and MondayEvening that do not match.

```
SELECT * FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.MondayMorning <> table.MondayEvening
```

@Ahmet
Try this to get the NULL in the columns

```
SELECT id
    ,date
    ,MondayMorning
    ,(CASE WHEN table.MondayEvening <> table.MondayMorning THEN NULL ELSE MondayEvening END) AS MondayEvening
    ,TuesdayMorning
    ,(CASE WHEN table.TuesdayEvening <> table.TuesdayMorning THEN NULL ELSE TuesdayEvening END) AS TuesdayEvening
FROM table 

UNION ALL 

SELECT id
    ,date
    ,NULL AS MondayMorning
    ,MondayEvening
    ,NULL AS TuesdayMorning
    ,TuesdayEvening
FROM table
WHERE table.MondayMorning <> table.MondayEvening
OR table.TuesdayMorning <> table.TuesdayEvening
```

Comment: I also have TuesdayMorning, TuesdayEvening and so on. What kind of query than I need?

Comment: @user1781398: If you have columns like that, I think your table is not well structured/normalized..

Comment: I agree with dotNETbeginner you should consider only having morning and evening columns the Date column will depict the day of the week.

Comment: This query is not working with my table. I Have a declare table.

Comment: @dotNETbeginner: I know but this is a existing table and I can't change it. I need to import the data from this table to another table. That is the reason why i want to have different dateparts into two records.

Comment: Well in that case I believe you can add this to the second Select statement. `code` OR table.TuesdayMorning <> table.TuesdayEvening `code`

Comment: Thank you Lourens and the others. This solution worked for me!

Comment: Question: How can I get one of the columns as NULL? Now I am getting the same records twice.

Comment: @Ahmet, the answer is dynamic unpivot followed by dynamic Pivot

Comment: @Lourens, I got a error when I have the data MondayMorning=0 and MondayEvening=2 Then MondayEvening is still Null.

Comment: @Ahmet, In this case what do you expect? Do you expect the 0 to be ignored / treated as a NULL?

Comment: @Lourens, When I have the Values Thursdaymorning:0 and Thursdayevening=2 then I get as result from your query a 0,NULL but I am expecting 0,2. Please see the link [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/5927) that the output is. Anyway I have another solution already using a cross apply. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
select id, date, mondaymorning as monday from yourtable
union
select id, date, mondayevening as monday from yourtable
```

(A union will remove duplicates by default)

Or more generically

```
select distinct id, [date], value from yourtable
unpivot 
(value for day in (mondaymorning, mondayevening, ....)) u
```

Comment: With what column need I to replace Value?

Comment: Value is a new column in the result set. It will contain the contents of your monday... fields.

Comment: Ok thanks. I am using a variable table so I can't use this approach.

Comment: @user1781398 what do you mean "a variable table"?

Comment: a declare table like: declare @table table (column int etc...)

Comment: @user1781398 Doesn't make any difference. Just put `@table` before the `yourtable` in the above.

Comment: I am getting the same count records. No difference if I use pivot. Can you send me your data how you tested this?

Answer (score 2):

Since you didn't specify what is your needed output, I have come up with the below. Let us know your actual output

```
Declare @t Table(Id int identity,[Date] Datetime,MondayMorning Int,MondayEvening Int)
Insert Into @t Select '2012-01-01',2,3 Union All Select '2012-01-01', 2,2

;With Cte As
(Select
    Id ,
    [Date],
    MondayMorning,
    MondayEvening,
    [Status] = Case When MondayMorning = MondayEvening Then '0' Else '1' End
From @t)
Select Id,[Date],MondayMorning,MondayEvening From Cte Where [Status] = 0
Union All
Select Id,[Date],MondayMorning,Null From Cte Where [Status] = 1
Union All
Select Id,[Date],Null,MondayEvening From Cte Where [Status] = 1
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

```
Select * from empmas where compcd=1 and empcd =0001 connect by level <=2;
```

Retrieves Employee 0001 Details and created two records of that retrieves record.

Comment: What does this have to do with the question asked?